# WITH RECURSIVE: is it possible to COUNT() the working table?

Tags: sql, recursion, common-table-expression, hsqldb, recursive-query

I am using HSQLDB 2.6.1, and I want to `COUNT()` the [working table of a recursive CTE](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_with_clause).

I wrote the following test:

```
with recursive
nums (n, m) as
(
    select 1, 1 from (values(1))
    union all
    select * from (     
        with
        var (k) as
        (
            select count(*) from nums   
        )
        select n+1, var.k from nums, var where n+1 <= 10
    )
)
select n, m from nums;
```

Here is the result set:

```
N   M
1   1
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   0
9   0
10  0
```

It seems like `COUNT()` does not work on the working table.

Was it not supposed to work?

And is there another way to count the working table?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done directly in the current version (2.7.0) of HyperSQL.

The column `n` of your query is incremented in each round, therefore counting the identical `n` values in the result table gives the size of the delta table for each round.

```
with recursive nums (n, m) as (
  ...
) select count(*) from nums group by n;
```

Comment: That's right, but your suggestion only lets me know count(*) values after the fact, not within the iteration (which is where I need to know them, in order to decide what to do in this iteration). But you say that it's not currently implemented, so at least I know why it didn't work.

Comment: In my specific case I may be able to use `RECURSIVE_TABLE` instead (is it a keyword?). From the documentation: "From version 2.6, HyperSQL extends recursive query processing by allowing the use of RECURSIVE_TABLE to reference the current general result of the <query expression>. This table name can be used in subqueries with an IN predicate in order to reduce and limit the new result created in each iteration." I could not find an example, can you show an example how to use it? And is it possible to count() it?

Comment: Subqueries containing aggregates such as count() on the RECURSIVE_TABLE do no give correct results as they were not implemented. Future versions may support them.